# Bootstrap shows a white background when moving between the last to the first slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, slider

I added bootstrap slider to my website and when moving from the last to the first slider (on mobile) I get this white background in contrast to the first and second slides which I can see they move as if they are connected.

I created this jsfiddle to show an exact example of my code and it works fine, but on my website it doesn't. 
Please review my CSS and tell me what am i doing wrong.

** I didn't set a fixed height for my slider .

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/La3wg8nu/

HTML:

```
        <!-- Wrapper for slihttps://jsfiddle.net/La3wg8nu/des -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="<?php echo STATIC_CONTENT_HOST ?>/static/images/slide1.jpg" class="slide1">
                <div class="carousel-caption Aligner-center Aligner-right">
                    <div class="Aligner-item-center Aligner-item-right">
                        <h1> text text text </h1>
                        <p class="item-txt"> potato text text more textx </p>
                        <p> <a class="btn btn-lg white-btn" href="https://example.com" role="button"> link here </a> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php echo STATIC_CONTENT_HOST ?>/static/images/slide2.jpg" class="slide2">
                <div class="carousel-caption Aligner-center Aligner-right">
                    <div class="Aligner-item-center Aligner-item-right">
                        <h1> text text text </h1>
                        <p class="item-txt"> potato text text more textx </p>
                        <p> <a class="btn btn-lg white-btn" href="https://example.com" role="button"> link here </a> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php echo STATIC_CONTENT_HOST ?>/static/images/slide3.jpg" class="slide2">
                <div class="carousel-caption Aligner-center Aligner-right">
                    <div class="Aligner-item-center Aligner-item-right">
                        <h1> text text text </h1>
                        <p class="item-txt"> potato text text more textx </p>
                        <p> <a class="btn btn-lg white-btn" href="https://example.com" role="button"> link here </a> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide { /*background-color: black;*/ }
/*.item {  opacity: 0; transition: 2s; }
.item.active { opacity: 1; transition: 2s; }*/
.carousel-inner>.item {  transition: 1s; }
.carousel-caption { font-size: 100%; }
.carousel-caption  h1{ margin-top: 0; }
.carousel-caption .btn-group-lg>.btn, .carousel-caption .btn-lg { font-size: 1em; }
.Aligner-center { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
.Aligner-item-center { max-width: 95%; }
.Aligner-item-right { max-width: 45%; padding: 0 15% 0 0; }
.item { width: 100%; max-height: 450px; min-height: 314px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03); background-size: 100%; }
.item:not(:last-of-type) { margin-bottom: 0px; }
.item:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 0px; }
.carousel-inner>.item>img { width: 100%; }
.carousel-caption { top: 0; bottom: auto; }
.item .white-btn { color: #292633; background-color: #fff; }
.item h1 { font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; color: white; /*font-size: 5em;*/ font-size: 4.4em; font-weight: bold; }
.item p { font-family: Hurme; color: white; font-size: 1.5em; }
/*.btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary:active.focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #ff4553;
}*/
.btn { width: auto; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; }
.lvl { color: #A49A87; }
.anumber { font-size: 30px; display: block; font-weight: bold; }
.aline { width: 45px; height: 25px; border-bottom: 5px solid #A49A87; display: inline-block; }
.atext { font-size: 18px; color: #484550; }
.gs-btn { margin: 30px 0; }
.gs-btn a { padding-left: 10%; padding-right: 10%; }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .Aligner-item-right { max-width: 45%; padding: 0 15% 0 0; }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .Aligner-item-right { padding: 0 5% 0 0; }
    .carousel-indicators {bottom: 0;}
}  
@media (min-width: 992px) {  
    .Aligner-item-right { font-size: 78%; }
    .Aligner-item-left { font-size: 78%; }
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {s
    .Aligner-item-right { font-size: 65%; }
    .Aligner-item-left { font-size: 65%; }
    .carousel-caption { font-size: 55%; }
    .carousel-caption { width: 100%; left: 0; font-size: 90%;}
}
@media (min-width: 769px) { 
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .Aligner-right  { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; -webkit-align-items: flex-end; align-items: flex-end; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; } 
    .Aligner-right p { text-align: left; }
    .Aligner-right  h1 { text-align: left; }
    .Aligner-left p { text-align: left; }
    .Aligner-left   { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; -webkit-align-items: baseline; align-items: baseline; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
    .Aligner-item-left { max-width: 45%; padding: 0 0 0 5%; }
    .Aligner-left  h1 { text-align: left; }
    .aline { margin-bottom: 11.2%; }
    .anumber { margin-top: 11.2%; }
    .atext { padding: 0 10% 10% 10%; }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .Aligner-item-right { padding: 0 0 0 0; max-width: 85%;}
    .carousel-caption { font-size: 59%; }
    .Aligner-item-right { font-size: 100%; }
    .Aligner-item-left { font-size: 100%; }
    .Aligner-center .item-txt { padding: 0 11%; }
    .slide1 { -moz-transform: scale(1.9); -webkit-transform: scale(1.9); transform: scale(1.9); }
    .slide2 { -moz-transform: scale(1.5); -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); transform: scale(1.5); transform-origin: 69% 1%; }
}
@media (max-width: 520px) {
    .slide1 { -moz-transform: scale(2.3); -webkit-transform: scale(2.3); transform: scale(2.3); transform-origin: 7% 31%; }
    .slide2 { -moz-transform: scale(1.6); -webkit-transform: scale(1.6); transform: scale(1.6); transform-origin: 60% 1%; }
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .carousel-caption { font-size: 50%; }
    .slide1 { -moz-transform: scale(2.6); -webkit-transform: scale(2.6); transform: scale(2.6); transform-origin: 10% 26%; }
    .slide2 { -moz-transform: scale(2.2); -webkit-transform: scale(2.2); transform: scale(2.2);   transform-origin: 49% 1%; }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
    .slide1 { -moz-transform: scale(2.9); -webkit-transform: scale(2.9); transform: scale(2.9); transform-origin: 8.5% 26%;}
    .slide2 { -moz-transform: scale(2.4); -webkit-transform: scale(2.4); transform: scale(2.4); transform-origin: 47.6% 1%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on your website so that indicates it's your extra CSS interfering. 
Take a look through all your CSS there and make sure you don't have any of your own classes with the names: `.active` `.item` `.left` `.right` `.prev` `.next` or any overriding `img` styles using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set a custom transition to the carousel item here

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
  transition: 1s
}
```

And the bootstrap carousel has a default transition of `0.6` seconds. Try removing your custom transition and you will see that the problem disappears

One way to solve the issue would be to edit the `bootstrap.min.js`

`c.TRANSITION_DURATION=600` change to `c.TRANSITION_DURATION=1000`

Or , if you use `bootstrap.js` (not minified )

`Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600` to `Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1000`

And then , instead of `.carousel-inner > .item { transition: 1s }`, you can add in HTML to your carouse `data-duration="1000"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem with left and right classes.
Make sure you have:

```
.active.carousel-item-right,.carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left){
    -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);
    transform:translateX(100%) 
}
.active.carousel-item-left,.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right){
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
    transform:translateX(-100%) 
}
```